# I can't get ng-repeat data to go on my page for visiting another user profile page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm am trying to fetch data by clicking on a user name to redirect the user on his profile page.
I am trying to do this with ng-click like this:

`<p style="font-size:11px; color: grey; " ng-click="seeProfile(gterest);changelocation();"><b>{[{gterest.author}]}</b></p>`

My two controller functions:

```
$scope.seeProfile = function (gterest) {
        console.log(gterest);
        var user = gterest.author;
        $http.post('/userProfile/', {user: user}).then(function (results) {
            console.log(results);
            $scope.userProfileList = results.data;
        })
    };

    $scope.changelocation = function () {
        $window.location.href = '/userProfile/';
    }
```

My server function:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.user;
    console.log(user);
    mongoose.model('Gterest').find({"author": user},function(err, gterests){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(gterests)
        res.json(gterests);
    });
})
```

And here I'm trying to display the data:

```
<div ng-controller="allGterest">
    <div masonry>
        <div class="masonry-brick pinterest" ng-repeat="user in userProfileList">
            <img ng-src="{[{user.image}]}" alt="aaa" style="width: 238px;">
            <p style="font-size:11px; color: grey; "><b>{[{user.author}]}</b></p>
            <p style="margin-top: 5px;"  ><b>{[{gterest.title}]}</b></p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't give me any erros but my screen is blank, I don't know what to do.
Please help! Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm am using {[{}]} insted of {{}} because I use handlebars a my view, so in my module file I have

```
app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you should use `{{your_varibale}}` rather than `{[{your_varibale}]}` . Below is the updated code.

```
<div ng-controller="allGterest">
    <div masonry>
        <div class="masonry-brick pinterest" ng-repeat="user in userProfileList">
            <img ng-src="{{user.image}}" alt="aaa" style="width: 238px;">
            <p style="font-size:11px; color: grey; "><b>{{user.author}}</b></p>
            <p style="margin-top: 5px;"  ><b>{{gterest.title}}</b></p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry my bad I forgot to mention, I use {[{my_variable}} because I use handlebars and in my module file i use app.config(function `($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});` so in my case {{}} = {[{}]}

Comment: Why are you using Angular Js and Handlebars together ? Entire property of Handlebars is handled by Angular Js  smoothly.